# How to query ALL Projects for all their WorkItems with a permanent Token in DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api

## Settings

I'm creating an Azure Logic Apps (which is one of the recommended tool from Microsoft for integration purposes) to fetch all "work items" and "projects" from Azure DevOps.
As I said, it is to integrate with other data sources in a Cosmos DB database.
I already integrated some of our internal cloud hosted software to the Cosmos database and I therefore have a working workflow which is, querying -> parsing -> formating -> publishing.

## Issue and question

I would like to use the best authentication method so that it is not linked to a single user, but more on the organization level. (If the "admin" employees leaves the company, I wouldn't want to have to regenerate a new token with the credentials of the new admin, etc)

*I would like to know which are the best avenues for this kind of project.*

Would associating the fictive Azure AD admin to the DevOps admin rights and using his account with an API Connection to DevOps be a good idea?
It seems messy to me and I was hoping something else would work.

The results to the queries would be integrated with other data sources from our other internal softwares to do BI reporting. As a mater of facts, all our other cloud hosted softwares had REST API in which you could create a permanent token not associated with a user, but instead with our license, and had all read-write rights. Why is this not a thing with DevOps?

## Things that did not work for me

I have already tried generating a token with my own account. I also asked our admin to generate a private access token, but they have expiry date and this is a problem to have our integration set-up.
I have also looked in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops), but all the methods seem to use user-related authentication, no full-scale, or organization-scale authentication.

## Expected Workflow

This is the desired workflow
[image: LogicAppsWorkflow]

Answer (score 1):

Like you've already researched, I believe authentication is always in the context of a user.

The only solution I see is to create a new user in AAD which you control and use a token for that user in your Logic App.